# ArrayindexOutOfBoundsException with Optimal Binary Search Tree implementation java

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree, indexoutofboundsexception

I am working on implementing the Optimal Binary Search Tree problem in java. for my program, I am reading in a txt file where the first line is the number of nodes, and each previous line is delimited by a space, where the first element is the node, and the 2nd element is the probability. Below is a sample input that my program reads in:

```
5
A 0.213
B 0.547
D 0.10
X 0.12
AAA 0.02
```

In my program, I am trying to create a print method such that when I run the program, I can see what node it is, what its probability is, what its parent is and what their children are. A sample output of one node is provided below:

```
Node
Key: B
Probability: 21.3%
Parent: (null)
Left Child: A
Right Child: X
```

The issue that I am running into right now is that it is reading the root of the tree fine, but then after awhile it will give me an index out of bounds. Below is my code for my print tree method

```
public static void printTree(String keys[], double prob[], int root[][]){
 System.out.println("");
int pos = root[1][keys.length-1];
int t=pos;

for(int i = 0; i < keys.length-1; i ++){

     System.out.println("Node Key "+ pos); 
     System.out.println("Key: "+ keys[pos]); 
     System.out.println("Probability: "+ prob[pos]);

     if(i ==0){
         System.out.println("Parent: null");
         System.out.println("Left Child: "+ keys[pos-1]);
         System.out.println("Right Child: "+ keys[pos+1]); 
         if(root[1][pos]==t){
             pos-=1;
         }
     }

     else{

         System.out.println("Parent: "+ keys[pos+1]);
         System.out.println("Left Child: "+ keys[pos-1]); //where the error is occurring
         System.out.println("Right Child: "+ keys[pos+1]);  
         pos--;
     }


     System.out.println("");
}
}
```

This is the output I am receiving when I run my code:

```
Node
Key: B
B is the root

Node Key 2
Key: B
Probability: 0.547
Parent: null
Left Child: A
Right Child: D

Node Key 1
Key: A
Probability: 0.213
Parent: B
Left Child: null
Right Child: B

Node Key 0
Key: null
Probability: 0.0
Parent: A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at OBST.printTree(OBST.java:62)
at OBST.main(OBST.java:155
```

> Obviously I have tried increasing and decreasing the size, but I am still getting and IndexOutofBoundsException at when I do that. I believe what the problem is, is that it is reading the root, and then it is going down the list and doesn't stop.

If someone could help me with this problem I would very much appreciate it!

EDIT:
I reconstructed my print method to include nodes, however I am still getting an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException. The following is an updated method that uses a nodes class

```
public static void printTree(int i, int j, int pos, String side, String keys[], double prob[], int root[][], Nodes[] node){

    int temp;       
    if(i<=j){

        temp = root[i][j];
        System.out.println("Node");
        System.out.println("Key: " + keys[pos]);

        System.out.println("Probability: "+ prob[pos]+" %");
        System.out.println("Parent: "+ keys[pos]);
        System.out.println(keys[temp] + " is the "+ side +" child of "+ keys[pos]);
        for(int k =0; k< keys.length-1; k++){

            if(keys[pos].equalsIgnoreCase(node[k].getKey())){
                if(side.equalsIgnoreCase("left")){
                    node[i].setLeftChild(keys[temp]);
                }
                else{
                    node[i].setRightChild(keys[temp]);
                }

            }

            System.out.println(" ");


        }
        constructTree(i,temp-1,temp,"left", keys, prob, root, node);  
        constructTree(temp+1,j,temp,"right", keys, prob,root, node);  

    }
```

This is the output I am receiving:

```
Node
Key: B
Probability: 0.547 %
Parent: B
A is the left child of B





Node
Key: B
Probability: 0.547 %
Parent: B
X is the right child of B





Node
Key: X
Probability: 0.12 %
Parent: X
D is the left child of X





Node
Key: X
Probability: 0.12 %
Parent: X
AAA is the right child of X



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at OptimalBT.Optimal.constructTree(Optimal.java:117)
at OptimalBT.Optimal.constructTree(Optimal.java:127)
at OptimalBT.Optimal.main(Optimal.java:90)
```

Comment: Node Key prints as 0 and node key is the value to pos. So pos is 0. What array location do you expect to get when you do keys[pos-1] which would be the same as keys[-1]?

Comment: My hope is that it would print to node 4, which is the right child of B. But as I see it the program is going from the probablility and going down. so if its starting at node 2, then itll print node 1 and then 0 and then error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I am making the assumption that you are trying to represent your binary tree as a 2d array.***

In your code you write:

```
 System.out.println("Parent: "+ keys[pos+1]);
 System.out.println("Left Child: "+ keys[pos-1]); 
 System.out.println("Right Child: "+ keys[pos+1]);
```

There are a couple problems here.

First off, your code implies that the right child is in the same location as the parent (both at keys[pos+1]). This is not correct. The right child is not the same node as the parent.

Second, you code implies that the left child is at keys[pos-1] and the right child is at keys[pos+1]. This is not correct. For any node at position "K" in an array, the left child of that node is at position "2K" and the right child of that node is at position "2K + 1".

Here is a nice picture that I snagged for the University of Alberta CS website. It should help you understand how 2d array indexes can be used to represent a binary tree.

[image]

[Source](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/tree-as-array.html)

I expect that your input is actually in this format, and you don't realize it. That would mean you actually have the following as input:

Node {name, parent, left_child, right_child, chance}

```
Node1 {A, null, B, D, 21.3}
Node2 {B, A, X, AAA, 54.7}
Node3 {D, A, null, null, 10.0}
Node4 {X, B, null, null, 12.0}
Node5 {AAA, B, null, null, 2.0}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem though that it keeps giving the indexoutofbounds exception though. this only helps solves the partial problem

Answer (score 0):

Indices don't wrap around like that. Your array keys has the indices going from 0 to `keys.length-1`. So when you do `System.out.println("Left Child: "+ keys[pos-1]);`when pos is 0 you are trying to access index -1, as you can see in your error message saying that your program couldn't access index -1.

I am however having a bit of a hard time trying to figure out what you exactly want. I also don't know how you insert nodes so I can't say if the prints are correct. So my answer is somewhat limited.

But based on your comment you want it to access index 4 when that happens which is `keys.length-1`. To do so you need to wrap around. The easiest way is by using modulo. So instead of using `keys[pos-1]` you'd use `keys[(pos-1)%keys.length]` or `keys[(pos+1)%keys.length]`.